# Creating a Custom list with Parent and Child items

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, custom-list

Is it possible to create a list with Parent and Child items in SharePoint 2013, OOTB or with SPD?

If not, is there any way I can link an Excel workbook uploaded into a site with an Excel Web Access WebPart and link it to a custom list?

For example, I change a value in the Excel Web Access which changes a value in the custom list it is linked to and starts a Workflow.

If this is possible at all in SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. You can't create true parent-child relationships, but you can make do depending on your requirements. If there will always be only one parent matching one or more children, you can write a workflow on the child list that will modify the parent item, then write a workflow on the parent item that runs when the item is changed.

Comment: I see, so I would have to make two list and make a custom view so they appear on the same list. I'm guessing I can't use the Excel Web Part either with a workflow right?

Comment: I don't think you can make them appear on the same list. You could put both on a page and send the parent as a filter to the child list.

Comment: Or you could make the child have a lookup to the parent item. This would let you display all items with their parents.

Comment: Alright, I will evaluate my options and proceed accordingly, thanks!